# Can I export default from a variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, next.js

I would like to change my `export { default } from 'MyFile'` depending on certain conditions, so can I replace the file with a string variable?

Currently I have something like this:

```
let exportFrom
if(SOME_CONDITION) {
  exportFrom = '../Something/Blah'
} else {
   exportFrom = './SomethingElse'
}
export { default } from exportFrom
```

This currently doesn't work as I get:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token

Is there a way to do this?

It is also important to note, that the reason I am doing this in the first place is because I am using nextjs, and one of my pages needs to be an error in certain conditions, otherwise it is just a react component which handles the content of it. So if this is not the way to do it, how do I solve my issue?

Comment: Did you look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)? It lists `export default expression;` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply export like this:

```
export default exportFrom
```

Or, using named export:

```
export {
  exportFrom,
  // you_can_export_any_number,
  // of_variables
}
```

For full reference see [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 1):

Just drop `{}`

```
export default exportFrom
```

Here's [**MDN ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Syntax)